# Json issue in Auto Complete using kendo ui

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui

i am using this document to use auto complete search http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/index.html

in this auto complete there is only the name while i want to use name and id

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
                 var data = [
                                {"value":"Albania","id":"1"},
                                {"value":"Andorra","id":"2"},
                                {"value":"Armenia","id":"3"},
                                {"value":"Austria","id":"4"},
                                {"value":"Azerbaijan","id":"5"},
                                {"value":"Belarus","id":"6"},
                                {"value":"Belgium","id":"7"},
                                {"value":"Bosnia & Herzegovina","id":"8"},
                            ];                 

                //create AutoComplete UI component
                $("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
                    dataSource: data,
                    filter: "startswith",
                    placeholder: "Select country...",
                    dataTextField: "value",
                    dataValueField: "value",
                    separator: ", "
                });


            });
```

this code is  working but how can i alert the the id when user select any country name

Comment: Instead of `{"value":"Albania","id":"1"},` use  `{"value:Albania,id:1"},`

Comment: @MIT: if possible simulate the same on jsfiddle.net

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/mitesh_inf/BFNtf/] (http://jsfiddle.net/mitesh_inf/BFNtf/)

Comment: `<input id="countries" />` This your  input select right, upon which autocomplete is called. then just associate a change event on it like this ,`.on('change',function(){ //when value changes,do something }) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is

```
                $("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
                    dataSource: data,
                    select: onSelect,
                    filter: "startswith",
                    placeholder: "Select country...",
                    dataTextField: "value",
                    dataValueField: "value",
                    separator: ", "

                });
```

there is event `select` and i call function `onSelect` that is

```
                function onSelect(e) {
                    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
                    alert(dataItem.id);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

1.You need to set dataValueField = "id":

```
$("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: data,
    filter: "startswith",
    placeholder: "Select country...",
    dataTextField: "value",
    dataValueField: "id",
    separator: ", "
});
```

2.Set handler on change event. If you are using MVVM:

```
onCountryChange = function (e) {
    var selectedCountry = self.AllCountries[e.item.index()];
    alert(selectedCountry.id);
});
```

Comment: there is small change check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You must drop the comma after the last element in the arrays. Now JavaScript sees a last, empty element and that does not support the .toLowerCase.

Comment: Please note that the author changed the original question after my answer. Originally he asked 'but it is not working there is error in console like this TypeError: d.toLowerCase is not a function});'